# modify a column in pandas data-frame selecting a sub-string

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

This is my pandas data-frame. I want to modify values of first column (System) by extracting just a,b,c,d. How can this be done in python

```
 System       mem
/vol/a/        10   
/vol/b/        20   
/vol/c/        30   
/vol/d/        40
```

Comment: Are they always the last characters before /?

Comment: yeah.. there can be strings also in place of a,b,c,d

Comment: as in multiple character? say 'abc'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using str.extract:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'System': ['/vol/a/', '/vol/b/', '/vol/c/', '/vol/d/'], 'mem': [10, 20, 30, 40]})

df['new_column'] = df['System'].str.extract(r'([^/]+)/?$')
print(df)
```

This yields

```
    System  mem new_column
0  /vol/a/   10          a
1  /vol/b/   20          b
2  /vol/c/   30          c
3  /vol/d/   40          d
```

Comment: what if there is also sequences like /vol/abc/.aggr and we have to extract abc

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
In [11]: df.System.str.extract("/vol/(.*?)/", expand=False)
Out[11]:
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
Name: System, dtype: object
```

Comment: what if there is also sequences like   /vol/abc/.aggr  and we have to extract abc.

Comment: @madhuri make the regex pattern `"/vol/(.*?)/.*"`

Comment: Now I think about it the `?` is not required here.

Comment: @AndyHayden: It is for strings like `/vol/a/.hidden/.git`, see OP's comment above. A bit unclear what he really wants.

Answer (score 4):

Can be done in multiple ways, here is one

```
df['System'] = df['System'].str.split('/').str[-2]

    System  mem
0   a       10
1   b       20
2   c       30
3   d       40
```

Option 2:

```
df['System'] = df.System.str.replace('[/vol/|/]', '')
```

Andy Hayden already covered str.extract

Comment: what if there is also sequences like /vol/abc/.aggr and we have to extract abc

Comment: str.extract would work best in that case, df['System'].str.extract('/vol/([A-Za-z]+)/', expand = False)

Comment: @madhuri, consider upvoting the answers and accepting the most helpful answer. It helps in closing the question and works as an appreciation for people who take time out to answer

Answer (score 1):

By using `rsplit` you can have as much stuff in front as you'd like.

```
df.assign(New=df.System.str.rsplit('/', 2).str[-2])

    System  mem New
0  /vol/a/   10   a
1  /vol/b/   20   b
2  /vol/c/   30   c
3  /vol/d/   40   d
```